# How to run a SyntaxNode at runtime

Tags: c#, scripting, roslyn

I am currently working on an REPL for a language that uses C# as an intermediate language, and after becoming lost a few times, decided it would be best to create a REPL for C# manually as practice. It uses `Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.CSharp.Scripting` to run such code. The closest I could get it to working correctly is:

```
const string prompt = "C# > ";
Script script = CSharpScript.Create("");

while (true)
{
    Console.Write(prompt);
    string input = Console.ReadLine();
    SyntaxTree tree = CSharpSyntaxTree.ParseText(input);
    script = script.ContinueWith(tree.GetRoot().NormalizeWhitespace().GetText().ToString());
    Task<ScriptState> t = script.RunAsync();
    t.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine(t.Result);
}
```

(Yes, I am aware that `while(true)` is a bad idea, but this is just testing.) This code *almost* works, but there's something wrong: it executes all the code every time. So calling `Console.WriteLine()` will actually write text every time. How can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: You want the `Submission` API.

Comment: @SLaks What is that and how do I use it?

Comment: See https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/csharpfaq/2011/12/02/introduction-to-the-roslyn-scripting-api/

Comment: @SLaks That tutorial appears to be outdated, there is no ScriptEngine class or Session class. The closest thing seems to beCSharpScript.EvaluateAsync(), but that doesn't seem to persist. Is there an updated version?

Comment: @SLaks I figured it out, should I post the updated code as an answer?